# Will xmlDocument.Load be overloaded if the input xml is over 100MB?

Tags: .net

We are using a tool that takes an XML file as input and converts it to CSV.  The tool is working fine for a 50MB file, but throwing an exception for a 100MB file.

After analysis I found that the xmlDocument.Load function is overloaded with the input.  Can you please suggest any way to deal with the errors?

Comment: What exception? Can you show the code that is throwing (or, even better, a short re-create).

Answer (score 3):

The `XmlDocument` loads the whole document to memory and builds a DOM tree of it. Thus, it throws `OutOfMemoryException` for large files.

Instead you could use the `XmlTextReader` which reads the document token-by-token. It requires some code to handle the structure of the XML data but using this approach you can read arbitrarily large documents without issues.

Comment: This is indeed what I would do here; a note to @Sreedevi on this, though: reading directly from an XmlReader is not always trivial (it rather depends on the XML, though)